# How to skip the first type of element in a list using XSLT?

Tags: xslt

I've got a list of notes, something like this:

```
<Notes>
    <Note>
        <Type>Internal</Type>
        <Value>STuff</Value>
    </Note>
    <Note>
       <Type>External</Type>
       <Value>Other stuff</Value>
    </Note>
    <Note>
       <Type>External</Type>
       <Value>Even More stuff</Value>
    </Note>
</Notes>
```

I need to list the External notes, but skip the first external note.  What's worse is that I can't always gaurantee the presence of an Internal note, so I don't necessarily know the position of the first External note.  So I guess I need to find the position of the first external note, and store that in a variable then use that in the test.  But not really sure how to do that with a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So I guess I need to find the position
>   of the first external note, and store
>   that in a variable then use that in
>   the test.

No. You can work with `position()`. How about:

```
<xsl:template match="Notes">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="Note[Type = 'External'][position() &gt; 1]" /> 
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Note[Type = 'External']">
  <!-- now do something with that node -->
  <xsl:copy-of select="." />
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: A little verbose because once you select the nodes, other nodes won't be applied. So, empty rule isn't needed and the pattern in the other rule can be reduce.

Comment: @Alejandro: I've removed the empty rule. Yes, this is push style, but I find push style is more expressive in this situation.

Comment: I didn't mean to adjective push nor pull style. Both are valid. For some cases (XSLT 1.0 's patterns restrictions) push style is handy. Althought, streaming (next conceptual step in XSLT world) is closer to pull style.

Answer (score 1):

Select the second `<Note>` that contains an `External` type:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="Notes/Note[Type='External'][position()&gt;1]">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Value"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- suppress -->
    <xsl:template match="Note"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which outputs the following when applied to your example XML:

```
Even More stuff
```

Comment: This would be pull style, but missing empty rule for other `Note`... Also, there is no need for encoding `>` character in attribute value.